# How to make a pulse alternator in minecraft 1.12.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to make a pulse alternator, so when a redstone pulse enters, output A on one side gives out a pulse, and when the second pulse enters, output B on the other side gives a pulse, and when the third pulse enters output A fires again (and so on). But I don't want the outputs to be sustained outputs (like a lever), just 2-4 redstone tick pulses. If anyone knows how to make something that does this, please tell me and screenshots would be appreciated.

Comment: Make the thing that turns buttons into levers, make a second output with a redstone torch, then put the thing that turns levers into buttons onto both. Probably not the most efficient way to do it, but the most intuitive.

Comment: Just hook the two outputs (one always off, one always on, but switching after each pulse) from a T flip-flop to a monostable circuit ("lever to button convertor") and add a repeater to the end to extend the signal a bit. I'd post an answer but don't have time :) You can look up what I mean online or somebody else can expand this to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A ring: 2 hoppers, 2 droppers, alternating, facing each into another in a circular fashion. Input signal activates the two droppers. Pairs: Comparator + repeater feed outputs A and B out of the hoppers. There's one item in this ring.

[image]

(the image shows the base level of the device. You will have connect the blocks marked 'I' drawing redstone between them above or below.)

This will activate the output A or B for duration it takes the hopper to eject the item into the dropper next to it. Next pulse on input I will inject the item into the other hopper. If instead of a ring you use a looping 'pipeline' of alternating hoppers and droppers, you can have as many outputs as you want.